# Stopping bounce when repeatedly jumping in spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a player character and a ground tile. On both physics bodies, I have `restitution` set to 0.

To jump, I directly set the `velocity.dy` of the player. When the player comes back to the ground due to gravity, for the most part it works, or seems to.

Problems occur when I repeatedly jump. If I jump right as the player lands, there's some bounce and the height the player reaches on the next bounce doesn't always match the initial bounce.

I've tried various ways to force the `velocity.dy` to 0 when the user lands, but nothing fixes the weird jumping issue. How can I properly and smoothly have a consistent physics jump?

[image: gif of issue]

Comment: I suggest you to use impulse to jump. Not modifying velocity directly.

Comment: you can use collision detection with ground tiles and set player.physicsBody.velocity=CGvectorMake(0.0,0.0); that would solve ur problem

Comment: Little known secret, just about all platformers use algorithmic calculation of movement, not physics. What do you mean by this: " If I jump right as the player lands, there's some bounce and the height the player reaches on the next bounce doesn't always match the initial bounce."

Comment: What physics are you using on your ground object?  You may be experiencing a force out because your sprite is going into the ground.

Comment: @Rocotilos that affects absolutely nothing.

Comment: @dragoneye Doesn't work. When would you set this to 0? In didSimulatePhysics? In update? In a collision handler? I tried all 3, and nothing seems to stop the bounce.

Comment: @Confused Watch the gif. Are you proposing that I select a height above the player, move the sprite there on a curve, then move it back down (unless it collides) to exactly the start point? That sounds like it could absolutely work, but it would be a lot of complexity if I could avoid it.

Comment: @KnightOfDragon it's a square for each tile with dynamic = false, restitution 0, large mass. The force out could absolutely be because of a slight entry into the other body, but how do I stop that? I've got usePrecisePhysics = true on the hero.

Comment: If Impulse dont work, try Force. I always confuse btw the two.

Comment: @StefanKendall the amount of time and effort that goes into movement of players (and enemies) in good/great platformers is incredible. If you look at (for example) the dev blogs of someone like SuperMeatBoy makers, or analysis of the different versions of Mario games, you'll find MONTHS were spent on getting the movement to "feel" right. It's the most important part of a platformer, and feels so good (in good games) precisely because it's been worked on to feel just right. And that feel is almost always algorithmic responses to movement rates, surfaces, etc. Faking fake physics, as it were ;)

Comment: This provides you with a degree of control over the experience, too, that's imperative for the design of levels and the layout of the challenges, obstacles, enemies, etc. And this is why it's the feel of jumps and running rates, recovery times, inertia and response times that's all worked on first, in graphical skeletons, before placing everything for each level and making more special movements like jump pads, springs, wind, etc.

Comment: I understand the temptation, to think those favourite platform games are just physics used to move the character, but it's generally not done this way because there's way too much variation in physics simulators, mostly due to the sorts of weird conflicts you're coming across, but there's many others, too. On iOS and SpriteKit, for example, the lack of delta-time means you can get all sorts of weird stutters in physics movement of a player, and that will really piss off the player.

Comment: You'll spend so much time compensating for and then trying to figure out where to put things relative to a physics engine's response that you'll go insane, despite the fact that it permits getting an initial playable game up and running easily, the long tail of production will be a wasteland of painfulness unless you make a very forgiving gameplay that's compensating for the "flexibility" of both the physics simulation, and the iOS interrupts that cause stutters.

Comment: @StefanKendall , make sure that your collision category is set to 0 on your tiles, I know dynamic = false is suppose to ignore this, but with Apple lately, who knows.  You can also verify at didEndUpdate that your sprite is not instersecting with your ground node, or figure out there what is happening.

Comment: You should not be modifying the velocity really. I  mean, for this type of game (i assume mario type game), you don't really need to do that. Just use applyForce.

Comment: @Rocotilos you may not always want to use `applyImpulse`.  `applyImpulse` takes mass into consideration, sometimes you want to ignore this

Comment: @Rocotilos that doesn't affect anything. They produce (seemingly) exactly the same result.

Comment: Have a look at my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Normally we shouldn't mess with velocities of objects. In a typical Spritekit game, we must treat it like a "real world" situation and generally apply force or impulse on the object.

I suspect you are trying to make a Mario-like game. All you have to do is apply a big enough gravity to the physicsworld and apply impulse on the sprite to jump (on touchesBegan delegate).

Just now I went ahead and made a simple mario jump scenario in Spritekit. And this is what I ended up with by setting gravity -30 for the y-component and impulse y=100 on the mario sprite. (Frame rate is bad. Looks better on simulator/device)

[image]

PhysicsWorld setup:

```
[self.physicsWorld setGravity:CGVectorMake(0, -30)];
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
```

Mario and platform sprite setup code:

```
SKSpriteNode *platform = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"platform"];
platform.position = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width/2.0,0);
platform.name = @"platform";
platform.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:platform.frame.size];
platform.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = platformCategory;
platform.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
platform.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection  = YES;
platform.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
[self addChild:platform];

SKSpriteNode *mario = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"mario"];
mario.position = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width/2.0, 400);
mario.name = @"mario";
mario.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:mario.frame.size];
mario.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = marioCategory;
mario.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
mario.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection  = YES;
mario.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = platformCategory;
mario.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
[self addChild:mario];
```

touchesBegan:

```
SKSpriteNode *mario = (SKSpriteNode*)[self childNodeWithName:@"mario"];
[mario.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 100)];
```

Comment: Turns out the bounding box I was using for collision that wasn't part of the movement/physics had mass, linear damping, and restitution, which pinned to my moving physics body caused all the issues. If you do this as @Rocotilos posted, this absolutely works.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. Glad could help. I like to add that you need to monitor the physicscontact delegate to disallow double jump (eg tapping on screen repeatedly). (On second thought, some game do have ability to double jump).. anyways you gotta handle that separately.

Comment: ps. Good luck with your game. :D

Comment: A sprite's physicsBody knows its contacting physics bodies, so when the user tries to jump, you can just make sure you're in contact with ground. (Ideally ground should be beneath you, but it's a similar check).